# excel VBA error: CreatePivotTable/The object invoked has disconnected from its clients

Tags: excel, vba

I have checked several forums to look for my problem but offered solutions don't seem to match with my code.

I created the following code which is quite usual (used it in many macros and never had a problem like this). I call this sub in another one. All variables are declared (some in public to use through the different subs). It eventually works but excel crashes for 4-5 minutes before it gives the result.

The crashing line is this one :

```
Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable( _
                   TableDestination:=StartPvt, _
                   TableName:="PivotTable10")`
```

I can't identify the reason. The only thing is that when I ask to recover it gives me the following message:

> The object invoked has disconnected from its clients

**Code**

```
Option Explicit
Sub point23()

Dim a, i As Long
Dim dict As Dictionary
Dim wb1 As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, ws2 

As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
Dim FolderPath1 As String, filename1 As String, FolderPath As String,     FileName As String,
Dim FC As Integer, FCC As Integer, LC As Integer, LR As Integer
Dim pvtCache As PivotCache, pvt As PivotTable
Dim StartPvt As String, SrcData As Range, pf As String, pf_Name As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

FolderPath = ...
FileName = ...

FolderPath1 = ....
filename1 = ....

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)
wb.Sheets(1).Copy Before:=Sheets(1)
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

ws.Cells.UnMerge

For i = 1 To 20
For j = 1 To 20
If ws.Cells(i, j).Value = "X" Then
FR = ws.Cells(i, j).Row
j = 20
i = 20
End If
Next j
Next i

ws.Rows("1").Resize(FR - 1).EntireRow.Delete

LC = ws.Cells(45, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LR = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath1 & filename1)
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets(1)

For i = 1 To 20

If ws1.Cells(1, i).Value = "X" Then
FC = ws1.Cells(1, i).Column
Exit For
End If
Next i

For i = 1 To 20
If ws1.Cells(1, i).Value = "X" Then
FCC = ws1.Cells(1, i).Column
Exit For
End If
Next i

Set dict = New Dictionary
```

'Perform Vlookups using dictionaries

```
a = ws1.Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, FC).Value
' Fill the dictionary
With dict
For i = 2 To UBound(a, 1)
.Item(a(i, FCC)) = a(i, FC)
Next
```

'Do the loop

```
ws.Range("a1").EntireColumn.Insert
a = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, FCC).Value
For i = 2 To UBound(a, 1)
If .Exists(a(i, 2)) Then
ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = .Item(a(i, 2))
Else: ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = "#N\A"
End If

Next
End With
dict.RemoveAll

wb1.Close

With ws.Range("A1")
.Value = "X"
.Resize(, 2).EntireColumn.Insert
End With

For i = 1 To LR
If ws.Cells(1, i).Value = vbNullString Then
ws.Cells(1, i).Value = "X"
End If
Next i

For i = 2 To LR
With ws
    .Cells(1, 1).Value = "X"
    .Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value & Cells(i, 12).Value
    .Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i, 4).Value & Cells(i, 6).Value
End With
Next i
```

'Create Pivot

```
wb.Worksheets.Add After:=wb.Worksheets(1)
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets(2)


  ws.Activate
  Set SrcData = ws.Range("A2").CurrentRegion
  ws2.Activate

  Set pvtCache = wb.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=SrcData)

Set pvt = ws2.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=pvtCache, TableDestination:=ws2.Range("A1"), TableName:="PivotTable10")

pvt.PivotFields("X").Orientation = xlRowField
pvt.PivotFields("X").Orientation = xlRowField
pvt.PivotFields("X").Orientation = xlRowField

'create columns of the pivot
pf = "X"
pf_Name = "Sum " & pf
pvt.AddDataField pvt.PivotFields(pf), pf_Name, xlSum

With ws2.PivotTables("PivotTable10")
        .InGridDropZones = True
        .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
End With

With ws2
    .PivotTables("PivotTable10").PivotFields("Xl").Subtotals = _
        Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    .PivotTables("PivotTable10").PivotFields("X").Subtotals = _
        Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    .PivotTables("PivotTable10").PivotFields("X").Subtotals = _
        Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    .PivotTables("PivotTable10").RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
    .PivotTables("PivotTable10").ColumnGrand = False
End With

ws2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
wb.Worksheets.Add After:=wb.Worksheets(2)
Set ws3 = wb.Worksheets(3)
With ws3
    .Name = "Sum X"
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With

ws3.Rows.AutoFit

ws.Delete
wb.Save
wb.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the line of creating a new `PivotTable` with the line below:

```
' create a new Pivot Table in ws2 sheet, start from Cell A1
Set pvt = ws2.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=pvtCache, TableDestination:=StartPvt, TableName:="PivotTable10")
```

Also, you can remove the code line below from your `Sub`:

```
StartPvt = ws2.Name & "!" & ws2.Range("A1").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
```

And replace the `Set pvt` line with:

```
Set pvt = ws2.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=pvtCache, TableDestination:=ws2.Range("A1"), TableName:="PivotTable10")
```

Comment: Hi , first thank you for the answer! However,I tried what you wrote (I will probably use for my next macros since syntax is simpler than mine) but I still get the same mistake.

Comment: @Raphaël  can u edit your post and add the rest of the relevant code ?

Answer (score 0):

For people with a common problem, I solved the issue regrouping pivot cache creation and pivot table creation in one line:

```
wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        ws.Name & "!" & ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), Version:=6).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:=ws2.Range("A1"), TableName:="PivotTable10", DefaultVersion _
        :=6
```